# SQL how to select multiple rows with the same ID based on criteria of the other columns?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to select the rows whose ID meets the criteria in column 2: first Apple then Orange. The desired answer would be the first 2 rows with ID = 1.

- ID,Column11,Column12, Column2
- 1, 1, 0, Apple
- 1, 0, 1, Orange
- 2, 1, 0, Apple
- 2, 0, 1, Apple

I added two supporting columns Column11 and column12 to label which row for one ID is the first, and which row is the second. Below is my code, but no rows are selected.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column11=1 and Column2=’Apple’ AND Column12=1 AND Column2=’Orange’
```

If I only use below, i got row 1

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column11=1 and Column2=’Apple’
```

If I only use below, I got row 2

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column12=1 AND Column2=’Orange’
```

Why put them together, I got nothing? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT ID FROM your_table 
    WHERE Column2 IN ('Apple','Orange')
    GROUP BY ID 
    HAVING COUNT(Column2) = COUNT(DISTINCT Column2)
)
AND  
(
    (Column11=1 and Column2='Apple')
    OR (Column12=1 AND Column2='Orange')
)
```

Comment: but will this select ID-=2 too? because ID=2 has one row meets Column11=1 and Column2=’Apple’ but does not meet the second criterion, which is column 2 = 'Orange'.

Comment: are you talking about adding another filter - AND ID= 1?

Comment: No, i know the desired answer would be the two rows from ID=1, I tried your first suggested codes and it worked. I do not know why the first suggested code does not return ID=2.

Comment: I think two row coming from ID 1 and another form ID 2. Is not it?

Comment: but you are using OR in    WHERE (Column11=1 and Column2=’Apple’)
OR (Column12=1 AND Column2=’Orange’). I am thinking, well, one row of ID=2  does meet the criterion before OR. why it is not selected?

Comment: Yes, this will ensure return a row if any of the combined logic is true.

Comment: I am thinking your first suggested codes will return row 1, 2 and 3. But the desired answer would be just row 1 and 2.

Comment: Row 3 meet the criteria you set (Column11=1 and Column2=’Apple’). So this will also come in the output.

Comment: agreed. So, my question is how to just select row 1 and 2 who meets first Apple and second Orange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194259/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-feifei-zhang).